# JAVA IDE - Conditional Breakpoints

Tags: java, ide

Does anyone know if there are any IDE's that can hit breakpoints on a condition?

For example, if I'm looking through a large list or iterating through a map or something, I may want to only suspend execution when an ID == "foo"

1.) Is this even possible to implement for IDE's
2.) Are there any plugins available for Eclipse to do this now?

Comment: I sure hope it's possible in a Java IDE seeing as that the C debugger I used back in 1989 on my PC/XT in DOS could do that.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, set a breakpoint at a given
>   location. Then, use the context menu
>   on the breakpoint in the left editor
>   margin or in the Breakpoints view in
>   the Debug perspective, and select the
>   breakpoint’s properties. In the dialog
>   box, check Enable Condition, and enter
>   an arbitrary Java condition, such as
>   list.size()==0. Now, each time the
>   breakpoint is reached, the expression
>   is evaluated in the context of the
>   breakpoint execution, and the
>   breakpoint is either ignored or
>   honored, depending on the outcome of
>   the expression.

Source: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F

Also, I believe you mean "ID == "foo"", because ID = "foo" will be an assignment and not a condition.

Comment: Excellent, didn't know about this.